# Flask: Working outside of application context

Tags: mysql, flask

I need to change some config parameters outside the init file.
So following the [manual](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/appcontext/) I use current_app.
But like they say:

> If you try to access current_app, or anything that uses it, outside an application context, you’ll get this error message: RuntimeError ...

Then they provide an example on how to manually push an app_context but it's not clear how to use it on a external file, like my case. How can I access and modify my app config parameters on an external file?

The code below currently produce the error I quoted above:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context

tools.py

```
mysql = MySQL()
current_app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
current_app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
current_app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'root'
current_app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'users'
mysql.init_app(current_app)
```

init.py

```
def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(12)
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved I needed to add this line to init.py

```
def create_app():
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(12)
app.app_context().push() # <---
```